# Converting standard number format to decimal format in excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I would like to convert a set of numbers in standard format (511241) to decimal format (5.11241) on Microsoft Excel 2010. I have tried working through with the decimal in the number format, but it considers the standard format whole numbers. Any suggestions would be gladly welcomed.

Comment: Can you show some more sample input and output? If all your numbers are 6 digits, just divide them by 100000.

Comment: Put `100,000` into a blank cell and copy it then select all of the other numbers and use Paste Special, Paste:=Values, Operation:=Divide.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I have tried these, but the numbers don't carry the same digit character size. For instance, some have 6 digits, others have 7, 8 or 12 digits.

Answer (score 0):

If the true value of all the numbers are less than 10, then the divisor will be 10 raised to the power of 1 less than the length of the number. You should be able to write a User Defined Function for that algorithm.